# Rendering a data.frame column of a tibble

Tags: r, dataframe, tibble

I want to create a data.frame with a column which is a data.frame. To format correctly this colum, I define a class (called idx) and provide a format method for it. It works if I first create an ordinary data.frame (here with two columns) and then add this column (the structure is kept, i.e. the length is 3). When I coerce my data.frame to a tibble, the structure is kept, but the rendering of the data.frame is lost (the data.frame column is rendered as two ordinary series)

I've read the "Extending tibble" vignette of the tibble package and I tried to use the pillar's functions that are described

```r
id = c("Alabama", "Alabama", "Kentucky")
year = c(1998, 1999, 1998)
gdp = c(4.5, 3.2, 1.4)
unemp = c(1, 2, 8)

idx <- function(id, time) 
   structure(data.frame(id, time, stringsAsFactors = FALSE),
                                    class = c("idx", "data.frame"))
format.idx <- function(x, ...)
    paste(substr(x[[1]], 1, 2),
          substr(x[[2]], nchar(x[[2]]) - 1,
                 nchar(x[[2]])), sep = ":")

z <- data.frame(gdp, unemp, idy = idx(id, year))
z
#>   gdp unemp   idy.id idy.time
#> 1 4.5     1  Alabama     1998
#> 2 3.2     2  Alabama     1999
#> 3 1.4     8 Kentucky     1998
names(z)
#> [1] "gdp"      "unemp"    "idy.id"   "idy.time"

# This doesn't work, but it does if I add idy to an existing
# data.frame

z <- data.frame(gdp, unemp)
z$idy <- idx(id, year)
z
#>   gdp unemp   idy
#> 1 4.5     1 Al:98
#> 2 3.2     2 Al:99
#> 3 1.4     8 Ke:98
names(z)
#> [1] "gdp"   "unemp" "idy"
z$idy
#>         id time
#> 1  Alabama 1998
#> 2  Alabama 1999
#> 3 Kentucky 1998
z$idy$id
#> [1] "Alabama"  "Alabama"  "Kentucky"

# Coercing to a tibble, I get :

library("tibble")
zt <- as_tibble(z)
zt
#> # A tibble: 3 x 3
#>     gdp unemp idy$id   $time
#>   <dbl> <dbl> <chr>    <dbl>
#> 1   4.5     1 Alabama   1998
#> 2   3.2     2 Alabama   1999
#> 3   1.4     8 Kentucky  1998
names(zt)
#> [1] "gdp"   "unemp" "idy"
zt$idy
#>         id time
#> 1  Alabama 1998
#> 2  Alabama 1999
#> 3 Kentucky 1998
z$idy$id
#> [1] "Alabama"  "Alabama"  "Kentucky"
```

<sup>Created on 2019-09-05 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

I'm still unable to get the desired rendering of the data.frame column

Comment: OK, I went into the rabbit hole and followed the trail from `tibble:::print.tbl` through a number of nested functions all the way to a call to `pillar:::flatten_colonnade`, where something equivalent to `pillar:::flatten_colonnade(z)` happens. I don't see an obvious way to solve this without rewriting `tibble:::shrink_mat`.